# Mercados financieros

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sobre mercados financieros esto es, para comprar y vender acciones, etc.
El problema es que no encuentro la forma de recuperar datos de las acciones(precio, variacion en %, etc.) y que se actualicen
automaticamente( lo que he visto que se recuperan del centro nacional de mercados de valores a traves 
de ficheros XBRL pero  no se como hacerlo).
el proyecto lo estoy haciendo en .Net y javascript.
algo parecido a esta web http://www.labolsavirtual.com/

Comment: Mencionas c#, pero que tipo de aplciacion desarrollas, es asp.net clasico o asp.net mvc ? que formato tiene el xbrl? es un excel, cvs, xml, json, etc La idea es obtener los datos desde codigo .net para procesarlos y persistirlos en alguna db donde puedas desde javascript tomar los datos mediente algun webservice o webapi ?

Comment: te estaba escribiendo una respuesta para lo que preguntas pero se cancelo la preguntas si entras al chat te la dejo por ahi Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que la extension `xbrl` tiene un formato xml que se podria parsear

[XBRL wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL)

Si tienes una `url` desde donde descargar podrias usar el se puede usar

[WebClient.DownloadFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

obtienes el archivo y lo procesas usando [Linq to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb387098.aspx)

Por supuesto parsear los nodos va a depender de la estructura del documento.

Una vez que obtienes los datos podrias registrarlos una db para luego consumir mediente servicios web que llamas usando `$.ajax` de `jquery`

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

con esto puedes consumir los datos parseados desde javascript

---

**>>he visto que esta api de yahoo devuelve un valores..en este caso Apple, google y Microsoft. pero no se muy bien como funciona para recuperar todos lo valores**

Segun puedo analizar del link. este devuelve un archivo de extensio `csv` por lo que los valores estan separados por `coma`

Para descargarlo usas lo mismo que comente antes el `WebClient.DownloadFile()` o `WebClient.DownloadString()`y para procesar los datos usarias el [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

---

Para obtener los datos de Stock Market usted puede consegirlos de muchas manera puede obtenerlos mendiante `cvs` por ejemplo:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GE+PTR+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr
```

o

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr
```

---

Aqui tienes una imagen con algunas `claves` `TAGS` (1letra o 1letra y 1 numero, el resto es la accion a solicitar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Imagen sacada de google image*

Ejemplo:

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/[NOMBREFICHERO]?s=[TICKERSYMBOL]&f=[TAGS]&e=.csv

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/[NOMBREFICHERO]?s=[TICKERSYMBOL]&f=[TAGS]&e=.csv
```

[NOMBREFICHERO] - Nombre del fichero para guardar("quotes.csv")

[TICKERSYMBOL] - Ticker simbolo de la compañia (para multiples Ticker separa por comas)

[TAGS] - La informacion del stock que solicitas ("sl1d1t1c1ohgv" por ejemplo)

Aqui puedes ver el Market, en tu comentarios dices el IBEX35:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=^IBEX

puedes observar los `ticker symbol` para cada compañia:

Sobre `ABE.MC`

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=ABE&f=snd1l1yr&e=.csv
```

Sobre `ABE.MC` y otros añadir el ticker separados por <kbd>,</kbd> por ejemplo o por <kbd>+</kbd>:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=ABE,AMS&f=snd1l1yr&e=.csv
```

---

Tambien puedes usar [Yahoo Query Language](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), entre otras puedes usar la API:

[Api Finazas Yahoo](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yahoo-finance-managed/])
Tambien puede mirar algo como:

https://openexchangerates.org/

http://www.financialcontent.com/support/documentation/json_quote_api.php

Comment: Gracias Leandro, al final el archivo xbrl no me sirve(si tiene formato XML). estoy usando visual studio 2015 c#, JavaScript. he visto que esta api de yahoo devuelve un valores "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=snbaopl1 en este caso Apple, google y Microsoft. pero no se muy bien como funciona para recuperar todos lo valores de un índice por ejemplo en España el Ibex 35. ni como utilizarla para que se actualicen automáticamente.

Comment: @trystan7 Recomendaria amplies la pregunta editadola con mas detalles, asi vuelven abrirla

Comment: tengo informacion que iba a publicar como respuesta si quieres la agrego a tu respuesta y tu decides si la dejas o la borras, estuve un rato escribiendo pero cuando fu a publicar no me deja. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel tienes idea como alertar a las personas que pusieron en espera la pregunta? vote para al reapertura pero no se si esto tiene algun efecto. Mas que nada para indicarle que si bien ellos no la entendieron otros si lo hicieron y hay respuestras que pueden ayudar. Si te deja editar mi respuesta y quiere agregar lo que has escrito no hay problema, en todo caso define algun separador y menciona que es un comentario tuyo. Si la pregunta se vuelve abrir dividimos las respuestas como debe ser.

Comment: no no hace falta tu lo miras y si te gusta lo dejas o lo adaptas o lo borras, por otro lado sobre lo de alertar no se pero, si le das a abrir o cerrar, eso aparece aqui -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/review en las pilas ya sea para revision o para cual cosa en este caso para abrir, pero algunas cosas si no se tiene cierta rep no se puede ver, un usuario que tiene digas 100 no puede ver lo mismo que uno de 1000 por poner un ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel no se si leiste el comentario de trystan7, habia mencionado a finance.yahoo.com, pero no conoce como recuperar por ejemplo "España el Ibex 35", en lugar de ponerle la lista de claves, conoces como recuperar los valores de indice que menciona ? digo para ir mas puntual con el ejemplo y completar lo que me estaria faltando, la verdad es que nunca utilice este servicio de yahoo

Comment: no se ahora mismo si se puede recuperar el indice entero sin poner los ticker, de todas formas acabo de poner un ejemplo para varias compañias  ademas le deje el enlace al indice que muestra las compañias que lo integran, solo tendria que cogerlas todas y ponerlas como se muestra el ejemplo de las dos compañias, no recuerdo si se puede traer sin poner las comañias, las claves son para decir que quieres que envie de esa compañia. Saludos